# Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details For WebView Application From GitHub

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, android-webview

I cloned a file for my website from GitHUB which was web-view-app. I was trying export my app after change all information. I exported from Build>Generate Singed Bundle/Apk but I'm getting the error.

This is the Error Message:

```
Task :app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
Note: D:\Android App\Accounting Software v1.0.0\accounting_main\app\src\main\java\com\webview\myapplication\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

And Error screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

My Java Code is here :

```
package com.webview.myapplication;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private WebView mWebView;

    private void requestStoragePermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed to download files")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", (dialog, which) -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE))
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
                    .create().show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @Override
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestStoragePermission();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        mWebView.setDownloadListener((url, userAgent, contentDisposition, mimeType, contentLength) -> {
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(source);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading File...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://account.founderitltd.com"); //Replace The Link Here
    }
    private static class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

I want to make a web view app which I'll publish on play store.

Comment: I given everything here. Code and Error message both are included here

Comment: Do a compile of the code using the  -Xlint:deprecation switch with the java command and it will list back all the deprecated API methods that have been replaced by newer methods, look them up in the API documentation to see the recommendations for those methods to replace.

Comment: What you have posted is not en error message but just a note. As you can see the compilation just continues. This is not the reason why the build process failed.